# Dealing with international phone #s and improper contact book formatting

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, abaddressbook

I've been holding off on posting this question for awhile, as there's several scenarios I have to deal with. Basically, our app uses Twilio to send an SMS with a verification code to a user's phone to confirm they actually own that device. We are glad Twilio as a whole can accept international phone numbers. However there are several huge issues on the local device which currently has us thinking we should only support/guarantee United States phone #s for now. But this is why I'm asking this question, to see if you can perhaps point me in a better direction.

So the problems are the following scenarios: Most users don't input the + and the country code for when they add contacts; aka proper formatting, which Twilio expects in the request body as: +15555555555. Our 'solution' was to strip all the garbage characters from the phone #s in the iOS contact book such as `()#+*-` and whitespace. We then add a +1 to the front of the cleaned `NSString`, which makes the phone # now a U.S. phone #, which is incorrect for other users of other countries. Most of our users will be U.S. citizens, but that's not an excuse for us to not fix this properly. Even if a user is a 'good' user and correctly formats their contacts with a + and the country code, we have to ignore it because the majority will not be correctly formatted unfortunately.

I don't believe getting the device's locale is an optimal solution either. Surely there must be a simpler and better way of doing this and not making ANY assumptions of where the user is? If so, could you please post some recommendations?

### **Edit: I took the rewarded bounties suggestion and this is what I ultimately came up with:**

```
NSDictionary *dictCodes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"972", @"IL",
                                       @"93", @"AF", @"355", @"AL", @"213", @"DZ", @"1", @"AS",
                                       @"376", @"AD", @"244", @"AO", @"1", @"AI", @"1", @"AG",
                                       @"54", @"AR", @"374", @"AM", @"297", @"AW", @"61", @"AU",
                                       @"43", @"AT", @"994", @"AZ", @"1", @"BS", @"973", @"BH",
                                       @"880", @"BD", @"1", @"BB", @"375", @"BY", @"32", @"BE",
                                       @"501", @"BZ", @"229", @"BJ", @"1", @"BM", @"975", @"BT",
                                       @"387", @"BA", @"267", @"BW", @"55", @"BR", @"246", @"IO",
                                       @"359", @"BG", @"226", @"BF", @"257", @"BI", @"855", @"KH",
                                       @"237", @"CM", @"1", @"CA", @"238", @"CV", @"345", @"KY",
                                       @"236", @"CF", @"235", @"TD", @"56", @"CL", @"86", @"CN",
                                       @"61", @"CX", @"57", @"CO", @"269", @"KM", @"242", @"CG",
                                       @"682", @"CK", @"506", @"CR", @"385", @"HR", @"53", @"CU",
                                       @"537", @"CY", @"420", @"CZ", @"45", @"DK", @"253", @"DJ",
                                       @"1", @"DM", @"1", @"DO", @"593", @"EC", @"20", @"EG",
                                       @"503", @"SV", @"240", @"GQ", @"291", @"ER", @"372", @"EE",
                                       @"251", @"ET", @"298", @"FO", @"679", @"FJ", @"358", @"FI",
                                       @"33", @"FR", @"594", @"GF", @"689", @"PF", @"241", @"GA",
                                       @"220", @"GM", @"995", @"GE", @"49", @"DE", @"233", @"GH",
                                       @"350", @"GI", @"30", @"GR", @"299", @"GL", @"1", @"GD",
                                       @"590", @"GP", @"1", @"GU", @"502", @"GT", @"224", @"GN",
                                       @"245", @"GW", @"595", @"GY", @"509", @"HT", @"504", @"HN",
                                       @"36", @"HU", @"354", @"IS", @"91", @"IN", @"62", @"ID",
                                       @"964", @"IQ", @"353", @"IE", @"972", @"IL", @"39", @"IT",
                                       @"1", @"JM", @"81", @"JP", @"962", @"JO", @"77", @"KZ",
                                       @"254", @"KE", @"686", @"KI", @"965", @"KW", @"996", @"KG",
                                       @"371", @"LV", @"961", @"LB", @"266", @"LS", @"231", @"LR",
                                       @"423", @"LI", @"370", @"LT", @"352", @"LU", @"261", @"MG",
                                       @"265", @"MW", @"60", @"MY", @"960", @"MV", @"223", @"ML",
                                       @"356", @"MT", @"692", @"MH", @"596", @"MQ", @"222", @"MR",
                                       @"230", @"MU", @"262", @"YT", @"52", @"MX", @"377", @"MC",
                                       @"976", @"MN", @"382", @"ME", @"1", @"MS", @"212", @"MA",
                                       @"95", @"MM", @"264", @"NA", @"674", @"NR", @"977", @"NP",
                                       @"31", @"NL", @"599", @"AN", @"687", @"NC", @"64", @"NZ",
                                       @"505", @"NI", @"227", @"NE", @"234", @"NG", @"683", @"NU",
                                       @"672", @"NF", @"1", @"MP", @"47", @"NO", @"968", @"OM",
                                       @"92", @"PK", @"680", @"PW", @"507", @"PA", @"675", @"PG",
                                       @"595", @"PY", @"51", @"PE", @"63", @"PH", @"48", @"PL",
                                       @"351", @"PT", @"1", @"PR", @"974", @"QA", @"40", @"RO",
                                       @"250", @"RW", @"685", @"WS", @"378", @"SM", @"966", @"SA",
                                       @"221", @"SN", @"381", @"RS", @"248", @"SC", @"232", @"SL",
                                       @"65", @"SG", @"421", @"SK", @"386", @"SI", @"677", @"SB",
                                       @"27", @"ZA", @"500", @"GS", @"34", @"ES", @"94", @"LK",
                                       @"249", @"SD", @"597", @"SR", @"268", @"SZ", @"46", @"SE",
                                       @"41", @"CH", @"992", @"TJ", @"66", @"TH", @"228", @"TG",
                                       @"690", @"TK", @"676", @"TO", @"1", @"TT", @"216", @"TN",
                                       @"90", @"TR", @"993", @"TM", @"1", @"TC", @"688", @"TV",
                                       @"256", @"UG", @"380", @"UA", @"971", @"AE", @"44", @"GB",
                                       @"1", @"US", @"598", @"UY", @"998", @"UZ", @"678", @"VU",
                                       @"681", @"WF", @"967", @"YE", @"260", @"ZM", @"263", @"ZW",
                                       @"591", @"BO", @"673", @"BN", @"61", @"CC", @"243", @"CD",
                                       @"225", @"CI", @"500", @"FK", @"44", @"GG", @"379", @"VA",
                                       @"852", @"HK", @"98", @"IR", @"44", @"IM", @"44", @"JE",
                                       @"850", @"KP", @"82", @"KR", @"856", @"LA", @"218", @"LY",
                                       @"853", @"MO", @"389", @"MK", @"691", @"FM", @"373", @"MD",
                                       @"258", @"MZ", @"970", @"PS", @"872", @"PN", @"262", @"RE",
                                       @"7", @"RU", @"590", @"BL", @"290", @"SH", @"1", @"KN",
                                       @"1", @"LC", @"590", @"MF", @"508", @"PM", @"1", @"VC",
                                       @"239", @"ST", @"252", @"SO", @"47", @"SJ", @"963", @"SY",
                                       @"886", @"TW", @"255", @"TZ", @"670", @"TL", @"58", @"VE",
                                       @"84", @"VN", @"1", @"VG", @"1", @"VI", nil];

NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSString *callingCode = [dictCodes objectForKey:countryCode];

NSCharacterSet *validCharacters = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+0123456789"]invertedSet];

for (NSString *sub in mutablePhonesArray)
{
    NSString *newString = [[sub componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:validCharacters]componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    NSString *newString2 = newString;

    if (![newString hasPrefix:@"+"])
    {
        newString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%@%@",callingCode,newString];
    }

    NSString *substring = [newString2 substringFromIndex:1];
    NSString *removeExtraPlusSigns = [substring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];
    NSString *finalPhone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%@",removeExtraPlusSigns];

    [newPhoneArray addObject:finalPhone];
}
```

Comment: I am looking a way to make this happen however it does not seems possible without keeping constant records (all country codes) and since your main target US, also you need US state codes. Because there are 25 different international call codes starts with +1 for different countries… 
International numbers: if someone keep a international phone number in address book  probably they calls that number and we can automatically assume there is + following by country code front of that record (or 00 following by country code).

Comment: Also checked SMS provider web page, it returns SMS delivery status, if you get FALSE you can always prompt to your user. But in any case if you can find a solid solution please update here I am really interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the calling prefix, first access the users current locale through the `NSLocale` class. Note that this does not require any additional permissions or private APIs.

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSString *callingCode = [dictCodes objectForKey:countryCode];
```

The use the country code to retrieve the pertinent calling code from a hard coded `NSDictionary` of all the ISO country codes and the corresponding calling codes which I have included below.

```
NSDictionary *dictCodes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"972", @"IL",
                                  @"93", @"AF", @"355", @"AL", @"213", @"DZ", @"1", @"AS",
                                  @"376", @"AD", @"244", @"AO", @"1", @"AI", @"1", @"AG",
                                  @"54", @"AR", @"374", @"AM", @"297", @"AW", @"61", @"AU",
                                  @"43", @"AT", @"994", @"AZ", @"1", @"BS", @"973", @"BH",
                                  @"880", @"BD", @"1", @"BB", @"375", @"BY", @"32", @"BE",
                                  @"501", @"BZ", @"229", @"BJ", @"1", @"BM", @"975", @"BT",
                                  @"387", @"BA", @"267", @"BW", @"55", @"BR", @"246", @"IO",
                                  @"359", @"BG", @"226", @"BF", @"257", @"BI", @"855", @"KH",
                                  @"237", @"CM", @"1", @"CA", @"238", @"CV", @"345", @"KY",
                                  @"236", @"CF", @"235", @"TD", @"56", @"CL", @"86", @"CN",
                                  @"61", @"CX", @"57", @"CO", @"269", @"KM", @"242", @"CG",
                                  @"682", @"CK", @"506", @"CR", @"385", @"HR", @"53", @"CU",
                                  @"537", @"CY", @"420", @"CZ", @"45", @"DK", @"253", @"DJ",
                                  @"1", @"DM", @"1", @"DO", @"593", @"EC", @"20", @"EG",
                                  @"503", @"SV", @"240", @"GQ", @"291", @"ER", @"372", @"EE",
                                  @"251", @"ET", @"298", @"FO", @"679", @"FJ", @"358", @"FI",
                                  @"33", @"FR", @"594", @"GF", @"689", @"PF", @"241", @"GA",
                                  @"220", @"GM", @"995", @"GE", @"49", @"DE", @"233", @"GH",
                                  @"350", @"GI", @"30", @"GR", @"299", @"GL", @"1", @"GD",
                                  @"590", @"GP", @"1", @"GU", @"502", @"GT", @"224", @"GN",
                                  @"245", @"GW", @"595", @"GY", @"509", @"HT", @"504", @"HN",
                                  @"36", @"HU", @"354", @"IS", @"91", @"IN", @"62", @"ID",
                                  @"964", @"IQ", @"353", @"IE", @"972", @"IL", @"39", @"IT",
                                  @"1", @"JM", @"81", @"JP", @"962", @"JO", @"77", @"KZ",
                                  @"254", @"KE", @"686", @"KI", @"965", @"KW", @"996", @"KG",
                                  @"371", @"LV", @"961", @"LB", @"266", @"LS", @"231", @"LR",
                                  @"423", @"LI", @"370", @"LT", @"352", @"LU", @"261", @"MG",
                                  @"265", @"MW", @"60", @"MY", @"960", @"MV", @"223", @"ML",
                                  @"356", @"MT", @"692", @"MH", @"596", @"MQ", @"222", @"MR",
                                  @"230", @"MU", @"262", @"YT", @"52", @"MX", @"377", @"MC",
                                  @"976", @"MN", @"382", @"ME", @"1", @"MS", @"212", @"MA",
                                  @"95", @"MM", @"264", @"NA", @"674", @"NR", @"977", @"NP",
                                  @"31", @"NL", @"599", @"AN", @"687", @"NC", @"64", @"NZ",
                                  @"505", @"NI", @"227", @"NE", @"234", @"NG", @"683", @"NU",
                                  @"672", @"NF", @"1", @"MP", @"47", @"NO", @"968", @"OM",
                                  @"92", @"PK", @"680", @"PW", @"507", @"PA", @"675", @"PG",
                                  @"595", @"PY", @"51", @"PE", @"63", @"PH", @"48", @"PL",
                                  @"351", @"PT", @"1", @"PR", @"974", @"QA", @"40", @"RO",
                                  @"250", @"RW", @"685", @"WS", @"378", @"SM", @"966", @"SA",
                                  @"221", @"SN", @"381", @"RS", @"248", @"SC", @"232", @"SL",
                                  @"65", @"SG", @"421", @"SK", @"386", @"SI", @"677", @"SB",
                                  @"27", @"ZA", @"500", @"GS", @"34", @"ES", @"94", @"LK",
                                  @"249", @"SD", @"597", @"SR", @"268", @"SZ", @"46", @"SE",
                                  @"41", @"CH", @"992", @"TJ", @"66", @"TH", @"228", @"TG",
                                  @"690", @"TK", @"676", @"TO", @"1", @"TT", @"216", @"TN",
                                  @"90", @"TR", @"993", @"TM", @"1", @"TC", @"688", @"TV",
                                  @"256", @"UG", @"380", @"UA", @"971", @"AE", @"44", @"GB",
                                  @"1", @"US", @"598", @"UY", @"998", @"UZ", @"678", @"VU",
                                  @"681", @"WF", @"967", @"YE", @"260", @"ZM", @"263", @"ZW",
                                  @"591", @"BO", @"673", @"BN", @"61", @"CC", @"243", @"CD",
                                  @"225", @"CI", @"500", @"FK", @"44", @"GG", @"379", @"VA",
                                  @"852", @"HK", @"98", @"IR", @"44", @"IM", @"44", @"JE",
                                  @"850", @"KP", @"82", @"KR", @"856", @"LA", @"218", @"LY",
                                  @"853", @"MO", @"389", @"MK", @"691", @"FM", @"373", @"MD",
                                  @"258", @"MZ", @"970", @"PS", @"872", @"PN", @"262", @"RE",
                                  @"7", @"RU", @"590", @"BL", @"290", @"SH", @"1", @"KN",
                                  @"1", @"LC", @"590", @"MF", @"508", @"PM", @"1", @"VC",
                                  @"239", @"ST", @"252", @"SO", @"47", @"SJ", @"963", @"SY",
                                  @"886", @"TW", @"255", @"TZ", @"670", @"TL", @"58", @"VE",
                                  @"84", @"VN", @"1", @"VG", @"1", @"VI", nil];
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out this was useful to me and I constructed a solution based on your help. See my edited question to see what I came up with :)

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad that I could help you out (sorry if my answer wasn't exactly what you were looking for)

Comment: It actually seems perfect and simple enough to me!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

You might look at using [libphonenumber](https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS).  Its got a pretty good phone number parser in it that will let you get E164 formatted numbers back out.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there something else that doesn't require a 3rd party library? Looks a bit overkill and bloated for what I need

Comment: Plus, as stated here: https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS/issues/5 There is no way for it to deal with invalid phone #s.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of anything else off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I'll answer.

THIS is EXACTLY what I am looking for. This post deserves more attention somewhere.

Warning: No need to worry about number length, Twilio should be able to catch every invalid phone number (unless you want to prevent server calls).

One Problem: If the user does not include a + symbol, i.e. 1-815-555-4387, the method adds an extra +1 instead of just +, check phone number length like so.

```
if (newString.length > 10 && ![newString hasPrefix:@"+"]) {
//                Add the plus and get on with it.
    return [@"+" stringByAppendingString:newString];
}
```

My one concern is that you have to reverse engineer this when you retrieve contacts, if you are matching users based on phone numbers in contacts.

So I believe, the best you can do, is assume any 10 digit number as a national number, and add the prefix.

```
//Fetch all Contacts   
       phoneNumber = [[phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                            [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
                           componentsJoinedByString:@""];

            if (phoneNumber.length == 10)
            {
//This is the original answer method
            phoneNumber = [self formatPhoneNumberForCountry:phoneNumber];
            }

 if (![phoneNumber hasPrefix:@"+"])
            {
 //Because I stripped off the + to begin with. 
                phoneNumber = [@"+" stringByAppendingString:phoneNumber];
            }
```

Comment: `[self formatPhoneNumberForCountry:phoneNumber];` what is this method I'm also facing same issue

Comment: It's the method in the answer, with a check for country code plus a plus symbol. The problem with mine is that i assumes you live in your native country code.